# Keeping updated with the Android Support Library revisions

Tags: android

Eclipse provides a single click and download for the support library for an android project, and it adds it to the libs/ folder as "android-support-v4.jar"

The above jar has no reference to revision number (currently r10), so surely (unless I use maven) how are other people keeping up to date with the support library revisions?

Comment: I believe it is managed be Android SDK Manager, when a new support library revision is available (usually along with new SDK revision), when you select to install, it will automatically uninstall the previous one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @yorkw, the SDK manager tells you which version is currently installed. Also, using the android tools -> add support library will in-fact install a newer version if available, you will see that later in the SDK manager.
If what you are asking is how you know a new version is available so you can update? than the answer is definitely SDK manager, as yorkw said.

Comment: It's a shame they don't version name the jars which get deployed via the eclipse tool. I guess the only way is to check and update at intervals to make sure you're using the latest version. Android need to change this IMO.

Comment: It could be nice to be able to see the current version where you have the option to install a new one, for sure.